# What is going on tf.train.shuffle_batch()

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am very new to the tensorflow framework and I tried this code to read and explore the CIFAR-10 dataset.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sess=tf.Session()

batch_size = 128
output_every = 50
generations = 20000
eval_every = 500
image_height = 32
image_width = 32
crop_height = 24
crop_width = 24
num_channels = 3
num_targets = 10
data_dir="CIFAR10"


image_vec_length = image_height * image_width * num_channels
record_length = 1 + image_vec_length

def read_cifar_files(filename_queue, distort_images = True):
   reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=record_length*10)
   key, record_string = reader.read(filename_queue)
   record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(record_string, tf.uint8)

# Extract label
   image_label = tf.cast(tf.slice(record_bytes, [image_vec_length-1],[1]),tf.int32)

# Extract image
   sliced=tf.slice(record_bytes, [0],[image_vec_length])
   image_extracted = tf.reshape(sliced, [num_channels, image_height,image_width])

# Reshape image
   image_uint8image = tf.transpose(image_extracted, [1, 2, 0])
   reshaped_image = tf.cast(image_uint8image, tf.float32)

# Randomly Crop image
   final_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(reshaped_image, crop_width, crop_height)
   if distort_images:

# Randomly flip the image horizontally, change the brightness and contrast
     final_image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(final_image)
     final_image = tf.image.random_brightness(final_image,max_delta=63)
     final_image = tf.image.random_contrast(final_image,lower=0.2, upper=1.8)

# standardization
     final_image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(final_image)
     return  final_image, image_label
```

when I run the following input_pipeline() function without tf.train.shuffle_batch() it gives me single image tensor with shape (24,24,3).

```
def input_pipeline(batch_size, train_logical=True):
    files=[os.path.join(data_dir,"data_batch_{}.bin".format(i)) for i in range(1,6)]
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(files)
    image,label = read_cifar_files(filename_queue)
    return(image,label)


example_batch,label_batch=input_pipeline(batch_size)
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
img,label=sess.run([example_batch, label_batch])

#output=(24,24,3) 
print(img.shape)
```

But when I run same input_pipeline() function with tf.train.shuffle_batch() function it gives me image tensor which contain 128 images with shape (128, 24, 24, 3).

```
def input_pipeline(batch_size, train_logical=True):
    files=[os.path.join(data_dir,"data_batch_{}.bin".format(i)) for i in range(1,6)]
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(files)
    image,label = read_cifar_files(filename_queue)

    min_after_dequeue = 1000
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
    example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image,label], batch_size, capacity, min_after_dequeue)
    return(example_batch, label_batch)
```

how is that possible. it seems that tf.train.shuffle_batch() take single image tensor from read_cifar_files() and return tensor which has 128 images.So what is going on tf.train.shuffle_batch() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tensorflow, a Tensor is just a node of the graph. The tf.train.shuffle_batch() function takes as input 2 nodes that are connected, thanks to the graph, to data.

So it doesn't take 'a single image' as input but a graph that is able to load an image. It then add a new operation to the graph that will execute n = batch_size time the input graph, shuffle the batch and returns an output Tensor of size [bach_size, input_shape].

Then, when you run the function in a session, the data will be loaded according to the graph, meaning that every time you call tf.train.shuffle_batch(), you will read n = batch_size images on disk.